# In Java, a primitive data type like "int" a class or an object?

Tags: java, class, object, types, integer

I read that primitive Java types (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, **`int`**, `long`, `float`, and `double`) and the keyword `void` are also represented as class `Class` objects. Then it means that `int` is an object of class `Class` then how come following statement doesn't throw error because `.class` is only used with class name?

```
Class c = int.class
```

Comment: "*[...] `int` is an object of class CLASS [...]*" - No. the `Class` instance returned by `int.class` is an instance of `Class`, representing the type of `int`. Primitives are not objects, they are no reference-types.

Comment: fine, then what is "int" if it is neither CLASS nor OBJECT?

Comment: Read [§4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html). All types are defined there. Primitives (`boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` ) are primitives.

Comment: The link(§4 of the JLS) says int is primitive that is known to me so should I assume that on primitive data type .class holds an exception because it can only be used with class name and int is not a class name but a primitive data type?

Comment: It is unclear since you ask in comment what is `int` but in the question you ask what is `int.class`. Make your choice please.

Comment: Please look at [@Andrew 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817822/4216641). He cited the corresponding JLS section defining `Class` literals there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `int` is a numeric type.
- `int.class` is a class literal.

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or **primitive type**, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed by a `.` and the token class.
>
> `ClassLiteral`:
>
> - `TypeName {[ ]} . class`
> - **`NumericType {[ ]} . class`**
> - `boolean {[ ]} . class`
> - `void . class`
>
> <sup>[JLS 10 - 15.8.2. Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)</sup>

Moreover,

```
Class<Integer> intClass = int.class;
```

according to

> The type of `p.class`, where p is the name of a primitive type ([§4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)), is `Class<B>`, where `B` is the type of an expression of type `p` after boxing conversion ([§5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)).
>
> <sup>[JLS 10 - 15.8.2. Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) all primitives have this. Like said in the document.

> The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long,
>   float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class
>   objects.

This is useful for reflection. That is why you can use int.class and all primitives types. So all primitives have a class... Even if they  are primitives. Kind of confusing but useful in reflection for knowing if it is a `int.class or a Integer.class`

Answer (score -2):

Java is a strong typed language, that's why variables must

to be defined before use in the program later.

Variables are the buckets or the containers which reserved memory locations to store values in computer memory. 
When you create a variable you reserve some space in the memory of the computer.

On the bases of the data type of a variable, Your operating system allocates memory and store
the value in the reserved memory.

There are two data types available in Java:−

1) Primitive Data Types
2) Reference/Object Data Types

There are eight primitives in Java:

byte (number, 1 byte)
short (number, 2 bytes)
int (number, 4 bytes)
long (number, 8 bytes)
float (float number, 4 bytes)
double (float number, 8 bytes)
char (a character, 2 bytes)
boolean (true or false, 1 byte)

[Checkout the Video Tutorial for Primitive data types in java](https://youtu.be/QwRLwfpUfU4)